# Kotlin/Android - setOnClickListener only works in one button

Tags: android, button, kotlin, onclicklistener, layout-inflater

I got a `recyclerView` with multiple items (`ViewHolders`). In one (ViewHolderItemTratamentos) of these I got the following elements:

[image]

When the first "add button" is clicked, through an inflator layout, the same elements (`editText` and `button`) are created beneath the previous ones. Just like this:

[image]

Till here, everything is ok. Another row is created with a equal `editText` and a equal `button` which got a different id, `R.id.btn_add_field_din` (from the layout inflated). This `button` right here got the same logic behind it. It inflates the same layout (same row). But then, this third button won't work, and it got the same id (`R.id.btn_add_field_din`). I also tried by `tag`, but it gave me the same problem.

**The problem is that I want to have many rows as I want it, but from the third button the `setClickOnListener` lost action**. Do you know what might be? Here's the code:

**ADAPTER:**

```
holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {

    holder.parent_linear_layout.apply {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
        holder.parent_linear_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_linear_layout.childCount!! - 0)
        holder.add_field_button.text = "-"

        //remove row
        removeField(holder.add_field_button, holder.parent_linear_layout)

        btn_add_field_din.setOnClickListener {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
             holder.parent_linear_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_linear_layout.childCount!! - 0)
             btn_add_field_din.text = "-"

        //remove row
        removeField(btn_add_field_din, holder.parent_linear_layout)
        }
     }
  }
```

**LAYOUT INFLATED (R.layout.used_products_field):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"
        android:inputType="phone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_field_din"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/botaoCard"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of maintaining views directly.
Maintain the data set. Take arrayList which holds all items which you want to display.
Now when user click add button just add new item to that list and notify your adapter.

Comment: @Moinkhan can you give that example in code? I'm confused about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you inflate the view yet using synthetic references to inner views.. I'm not sure it works this way because `R` is created on compilation, not runtime. And I suppose you use multiple ViewHolder of this kind inside the RecyclerView. In which case, the same ID would be set to multiple Views, which is not possible.

My guess is that `btn_add_field_din` does not reference the view you think. Inspect it. Try to set a background `Color.RED` see if that's the right view.

Also, `removeField(btn_add_field_din, holder.parent_linear_layout)` seems to remove the view, does it?

Comment: yes, the removeField remove the view, it's not relevant for my question. I've inspected and it is, is the view I think, unfortunately. Yes, the id is multiplicated... but it need to be, to do the action, right? Thank you for your atention.

Comment: Do not duplicate the view. Use a good-old `findViewById` for such cases. Also, if you remove the view using `removeField()` then how would a listener respond to it?

Comment: The remove the view is optional, you don't need to click it. But how am I supose to use the findViewById? I need that all the next "btn_add_field_din" to do the action, the inflate... and onyl the first works.

Comment: Ok. `rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_field_din).setOnClickListener` should be more specific. You got the idea.

Comment: All the buttons got the same id ("btn_add_field_din"), except the first. And only the first "btn_add_field_din" works.